# Help making nrf51822 work (PTR5518)

Tags: arm

I have a PTR5518 module which has nRF51822 SoC. I also have nRF51 SDK and STM32F discovery board (which has debugger with SWD and SCLK pins). I have sample codes as well.
I need help as how can I get my code (which is in .c) to compile and into PTR5518. I am stuck here for over few weeks now and am really losing hope. Being new to ARM any help or steps would be really lifesaving.

[Details of module I have](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SLboat-nRF51822-Small-Module-Blur-nRF-11-GPIO-15-15-2-Size-/171202444586)

Comment: I have just seen your post, not sure if you have managed to get things working. I am also new to ARM and programming them/bluetooth but I managed to get my PTR5518 and a modified Nordic PCA10001 working. Bit of an struggle but managed to get it working. I use Keil for the IDE and use the nRFgoStudio to program the module which uses the SWIO & SWCLK of the PCA10001. I havent got further than flashing the ble_app_hrs example in to the unit and testing it, but if you still need help, I will be happy to share with you my findings.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to register with Nordic to get the development environment for the CortexM0 that's on the nRF51822.  If your module was intended to be programmed, it would have come with some sort of product key that lets you do this.  Alternatively, if your module is not intended to be third-party programmed, and is just designed to interface with your system via some serial protocol, you would not have received this code, and you would just program your own system to interact with it.

You'll also need a programmer to program it.  I'm not sure the ST-link on your Discovery board is capable of this.

Comment: There are several web pages which claim the st-link works.

Comment: I have registered on Nordic as well as purchased the latest development kit along with the environment. My module is standard third-party module approved by nordic on its webpage. I am able to program nRF51822 on sd kit but how do I program my third-party module?

Comment: You need to provide power and ground to the module and break out SWDIO and SWClock (pins 4 and 5), and attach them to your programmer, as shown on page 2 of the board docs on ebaly